# Calculating a percentage from a "list", R

Tags: r

I have 15 deer with which i am analysing there used and expected data points extracted from a slope tif. file. Currently i am analysing the expected data and have a problem with calculating the percentage

Packages used are the raster package, rgdal, and psych packages.
DATA LAYOUT: My data is displayed in "list" format and is displayed for each individual (i.e.15 rows) each with the structure:

```
Deer01: 2 1 5 4 2 3 2 2
```

(where the numbers represent the category of slope incline). However, i now want to try to calculate the total number of 5's or 2's (representing slope) across all deer together and convert this to a percentage.

**Problem:** I do not know how to calculate the proportion of category 5's (or 2's etc) from the "list" data structure described above and need help.
I guess i must sum the rows / columns or something but i am unsure how. Does someone know how? As is apparent from the syntax below there is only 1 column heading which refers to the ID (Deer) column (see structure typed in paragraph above).

Here is the full syntax i used within 50% home ranges:

```
install.packages("raster")
library(raster)
install.packages("rgdal")
library(rgdal)
Slope<-raster("C:\\REWORK\\SLOPE011.tif")
plot(Slope)
Slope
str(Slope)
install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
```

Calculate and categorise 50% Expected Slope values

```
m <- matrix (c(0, 5, 1,
5, 10, 2,
10, 15, 3,
15, 20, 4,
20, Inf, 5), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

r2 <- reclassify(Slope, m)
r2
plot(r2)

All50HRs<-shapefile("L:\\GPSdatabackup\\KERNELS\\NewHRs50")
plot(All50HRs)
All50HRs
library(raster)
update.packages("raster")
```

Attempt to extract slope by spatial polygons" using vector format and maintaining Object_ID
Here data is required in a "list" format

```
Exp50poly <- extract(r2, All50HRs)
names(Exp50poly)<-All50HRs$Object_ID
str(Exp50poly)
```

This section was my attempt at trying to get a proportional value from the data shown in str(Exp50poly) but it doesn't seem to work

```
Exp50polycov.table50.sum<-colSums(Exp50polycov.table50)
Exp50polycov.table50.sum<-Exp50polycov.table50.sum/sum(Exp50polycov.table50.sum)
Exp50polycov.table50.sum
```

To try and help people see my data structure i have copied some data from the console where i see my data. see below (the left no' is just an ID with the Slope codes to the right). This is repeated 15 times for each individual

```
dr_12_008_11: num [1:2089] 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 1 1 2...
dr_14_011_12: num [1:5260] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2...
dr_10_012_14: num [1:710] 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2..
```

Hope someone can help, thanks

Comment: You are using terminology which i suspect is shared only by other users of some unnamed package or discipline. Perhaps you should either present a complete example (and explain your understanding of the term "circle") or consider finding a mailing list for users of this package or who share your understanding of these terms.

Comment: extract? Are you using the raster package? This is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to answer without seeing how you've shaped your data.

I assume your data looks something like this:

```
 Circle   Habitat
 circle25    1   
 circle14    2
```

If that is the case you can simply add a new column and populate each row with 1:

```
dataframe$Proportion <- 1
```

Following that you can then calculate the percentage of each type of habitat by circle type using aggregate:

```
Percentage <- aggregate(dataframe$Proportion,
                by=list(dataframe$Circle,dataframe$Habitat),FUN="mean")
```

This is complete guesswork based on your vague question so I may not be correctly answering.

If you just want the percentage of habitats overall use the same aggregate but drop the circle column:

```
Percentage <- aggregate(dataframe$Proportion,
                by=list(dataframe$Habitat),FUN="mean")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and below i have tried to provide a much more detailed description of my problem as my previous description i admit was somewhat vague.

Comment: Where is the new description?

Comment: I'm analysing 'used' and 'expected' slope data, for 15 individual deer with home ranges (e.gAllHRs50 or polygons). I'm currently calculating the expected slope values using these "available areas" (polygons, see syntax below):                 m <- matrix (c(0, 5, 1,
            5, 10, 2,
            10, 15, 3,
            15, 20, 4,
            20, Inf, 5), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

r2 <- reclassify(Slope, m)
r2

All50HRs<-shapefile("L:\\GPSdatabackup\\KERNELS\\NewHRs50")
All50HRs
Exp50poly <- extract(r2, All50HRs)
names(Exp50poly)<-All50HRs$Object_ID
str(Exp50poly)

Comment: I'm analysing 'used' and 'expected' slope data, for 15 individual deer with home ranges (e.gAllHRs50 or polygons). I'm currently calculating the expected slope values using these "available areas" (polygons, see syntax below)  #Here i classify slope data: library(raster)      m <- matrix (c(0, 5, 1,
            5, 10, 2,
            10, 15, 3,
            15, 20, 4,
            20, Inf, 5), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

r2 <- reclassify(Slope, m)
r2
All50HRs<-shapefile("L:\\GPSdatabackup\\KERNELS\\NewHRs50")
All50HRs
Exp50poly <- extract(r2, All50HRs)
names(Exp50poly)<-All50HRs$Object_ID
str(Exp50poly)

Comment: It would be much clearer if you edited the original question and added the contents of your data frame. Seeing the shape of the data (the columns and the contents in the rows) would be useful.

Comment: Just to also say as i ran out of space in the previous comment i did use the raster package, rgdal, and psych packages. As for data structure each row has the following structure ("list"): "Deer1, 1,5,3,2,5,1,1,1,3". This is repeated 15 times for each individual. As this is a "list" i have not got a clear column heading as you suggested in your reply. However, i now want to try to calculate the number of 5's or 2's (representing slope) across all deer together. P.S.Disregard information i sent in the initial question yesterday but link these comments to the full syntax i sent earlier.